# Ways to access global context from within a function?

Tags: php, global-variables, scope

Are there any other ways to access global context from within a function scope in PHP, outside of `$GLOBALS` and `global`?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to reference [the PHP manual page on variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope), which lists two ways to access variables in the global scope: the `global` keyword and the `$GLOBALS` superglobal.  These are your only options.